# android what the difference between remoteMessage.getData().get("body") And remoteMessage.getnetification.getBody()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

some help please

i try to send ussdcode through FCM when i send the ussd as body in FCM it work

in foreground but in background and kill doesn't work in (some device) what is

the problem please

here is my code :

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    boolean isEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
     remoteMessage.getData();
    Log.e(" remoteMessage", " remoteMessage.getData(): "+ remoteMessage.getData() );
    ussdCode=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Log.e("ussdCode", "body: "+ussdCode );
 //   blue=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();

    if (ussdCode.equalsIgnoreCase("on")){
        if (!isEnabled){
            setBluetooth(true);
        }
        else {

        }

    }
    else if(ussdCode.equalsIgnoreCase("off")){

        if (isEnabled){
            setBluetooth(false);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    else {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("ussdcode",ussdCode);
        editor.commit();
        UssdShow(ussdCode);
    }
```